# Scipyを用いた2階常微分方程式のプログラムについて

Tags: python, python3, scipy

現在
https://www.eidos.ic.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~tau/lecture/computational_physics/text/4-matplot-numpy.pdf
こちらのサイトをPythonの自学学習として利用させていただいています。係数行列A、ベクトルfまでは作成できたのですが、この先がどうしてもわかりません。何かアドバイスやヒントを教えていただけると幸いです。

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import *
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


n=10
m=2.0
k=2.0
x0=0.0

X=np.zeros((n,2))
print(X)

StartTime=0.0
EndTime=30.0
dt=0.01

Count=int((EndTime-StartTime)/dt)

A=np.arange(n*n).reshape(n,n)
for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range(0,n):
        if j==i:
            A[i][j]=2
        elif j==i-1 or j==i+1:
            A[i][j]=-1
        else:
            A[i][j]=0
A[9][9]=1
A=A*(-k/m)
print(A)

f=np.zeros((n,1))
f[0][0]=-x0*(-k/m)
print(f)
```

このようなプログラムを作成し、

```
[[0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]]
[[-2.  1. -0. -0. -0. -0. -0. -0. -0. -0.]
 [ 1. -2.  1. -0. -0. -0. -0. -0. -0. -0.]
 [-0.  1. -2.  1. -0. -0. -0. -0. -0. -0.]
 [-0. -0.  1. -2.  1. -0. -0. -0. -0. -0.]
 [-0. -0. -0.  1. -2.  1. -0. -0. -0. -0.]
 [-0. -0. -0. -0.  1. -2.  1. -0. -0. -0.]
 [-0. -0. -0. -0. -0.  1. -2.  1. -0. -0.]
 [-0. -0. -0. -0. -0. -0.  1. -2.  1. -0.]
 [-0. -0. -0. -0. -0. -0. -0.  1. -2.  1.]
 [-0. -0. -0. -0. -0. -0. -0. -0.  1. -1.]]
[[0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]]
```

この結果を得ています。

Comment: Yutoさん、もしかしてアカウントがふたつに分かれてしまっていませんでしょうか？　質問の投稿者であれば自由に内容を編集できます。もし分かれてしまった場合、[こちらのヘルプページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)からアカウントを統合できます :)

Comment: 「この先が分かりません」ではなく、具体的に何をするプログラムが書けないのかを書いて頂けると答えやすいです。